# Segmentation fault using operator delete in C ++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, delete-operator

I'm trying to make a program work in c++. When I create an instance of a class and take the reference to it, everything is fine:

```
PolyCRTBuilder test1(parms);
PolyCRTBuilder *p = &test1;
```

But when I use dynamic allocation to create the instance, it gives me a segmentation fault error as I try to free the memory:

```
PolyCRTBuilder *test2 = new PolyCRTBuilder(parms);
cout << "test2 variable created" << endl;
delete [] test2;
cout << "test2 variable deleted" << endl;
```

This last code returns me

> test2 variable created
>
> Segmentation fault

Why is this?

Comment: Use the operator delete instead of the operator delete [].

Comment: @vlad-from-moscow Oh my god, you are right!! What a shame... Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delete [] test2;` deletes an array, but you create a normal object. Try `delete test2;` instead.

You should also familiarize youself with smart pointers, for example unique_ptr and shared_ptr. Raw pointers are bad style in modern C++ and makes you program error prone.

Answer (score 0):

You use `delete[]` if you allocated with `new []`

that is for array allocation

Do not mix them.

so you allocated:

`new PolyCRTBuilder(parms);`

so, just delete like this

`delete test2;`

Answer (score 0):

```
PolyCRTBuilder test1(parms);
PolyCRTBuilder *p = &test1;
```

As you can see this is not dynamic memory as you know it can not be deleted with delete operator

```
PolyCRTBuilder *test2 = new PolyCRTBuilder(parms);
cout << "test2 variable created" << endl;
delete  test2;
cout << "test2 variable deleted" << endl;
```

but when you create a dynamic memory you have to delete at the end so this is only single variable and can be delete with  `delete` operator so use delete as above describe.